# how to calculate the percentage and then add how to add to the dict in python?

Tags: python

I have a dict as follows

```
      aDict = {0:{'x':22, 'y':42}, 1:{'x':42, 'y':55}}
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage of x to the y and then add the result with key 'z' in each dictionary inside aDict.
How to acheive it?Should ignore if there are no x and y values inside each dict..

Thank you.

Comment: what did you try ? Show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a dictionary where one element is missing the x and y values:

```
>>> aDict = {0:{'x':22, 'y':42}, 1:{'x':42, 'y':55}, 2:{}}
>>> for key,value in aDict.items():
...     try:
...             value['z'] = 100 * value['x'] / float(value['y'])
...     except KeyError:
...             continue
... 
>>> aDict
{0: {'y': 42, 'x': 22, 'z': 52.38095238095238}, 1: {'y': 55, 'x': 42, 'z': 76.36363636363636}, 2: {}}
```

Comment: this will raise the error if there is no x and y in the dictionary.How to avoid that?

Comment: what if there are two dicts with x in one dict and y in another?how to calculate and add z to either of the dict then?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: aDict = {0:{'x':23}, 1:{'x':42}}
aDict1 = {0:{'y':42}, 1:{'y':21}}
now I want to calculate the percentage and then add that z value to either of the dict?
O/p: aDict = {0:{'x':23, 'z': percent}, 1:{'x':42, 'z':percent}}
percent is b/w x and y with same keys in two dicts.

Comment: I don't get it. What should the output be then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`dict.iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) to iterate over your dictionary:

```
for key, value in aDict.iteritems():
    value['z'] = int(100.0 / (float(value['y']) / float(value['x'])))
```

Comment: int(100.0 * (float(value['y']) / float(value['x'])))

Comment: No. Either `100 / y / x` or `100 * x / y` but never `100 * y / x`.

Comment: Sorry my bad i saw it as x/y